# Group by users throws error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model `Reminder` with the fields:

```
:text,  :name,  :user_id
```

As you can see i refernce to the user.

Now i tried to make a query that should group the reminders by the users:

```
Reminder.group(:user_id)
```

I saw a lot of the same problems on stackoverflow but somehow i still couldnt fix this error:

```
Grouping error: ERROR:  column "reminders.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an    aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "reminders".* FROM "reminders"  GROUP BY user_id
```

What did i wrong?

Comment: You can't select * with a group by. all columns must either be included in the group by or they must be listed in the select clause with an aggregate function like sum or max.

Comment: What are you trying to do btw, find duplicate user_id's?

Comment: @JLampon i would like to have it listed somehow like that: `1 => [blabal], 23 => [holso] ..`

Comment: The numbers shoud be the patient_ids and the `[blaba]` should be the data of the reminders

Comment: If you just want to see everything, but want the id's to be next to each other try Order By instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find duplicate user_id entries and see the data you can do the following:

`Select reminders.*
From reminders
Where user_id exists (Select user_id, Count(*)
                      From reminders
                      Group By user_id
                      Having Count(*) > 1)`

See if that works.